# Opening CSV file as Notepad then new line not seen

Tags: java, csv, notepad

My Java code produce csv file. when I open this CSV file as Notepad, I can not seen new line. I see all data just one line. 
Because of this reason , I can not add this file SQL database.

How can I solve this problem? 
For example, test.csv file :

```
TerminalSerialNo    IMEI    Site-Ref
77EC0067C8A1BA6462FCA25F8B1DFBE289F6A3EE    null    SIT-3
01B406234550B1A688000050BF7A60E2    null    SIT-3
19B32E9399CB51FACF858E126F9C7684578A8BAC    null    SIT-7
```

When I open this file as Notepad:

```
TerminalSerialNo,IMEI,Site-Ref,Site-Name77EC0067C8A1BA6462FCA25F8B1DFBE289F6A3EE,null,SIT3,01B406234550B1A688000050BF7A60E2,null,SIT-3,19B32E9399CB51FACF858E126F9C7684578A8BAC,null,SIT-7
```

What can I do to see data in Notepad with new line as CSV file?

Best Regards

Comment: try other text editors like notepad++ and vs-code

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing any code, but my wild guess is you're saving file with Unix-style newlines (\n) and you're opening the file on Windows and Notepad expects Windows-style newlines (\r\n). You can check this using some modern text editor like Notepad++.

Comment: A quick google search would have gotten you this answer on the Super User SE: https://superuser.com/questions/362087/notepad-ignoring-linebreaks Credit to Paul for the answer there.

Comment: I know, when notepad ++ it seems ok. But I want to see like this in notepad. But the problem I want to solve in this notepad. If I solve , I easily add this file in SQL. Otherwise, SQL give me error while uploading data.

Comment: `FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("output.csv"); 

     // headers
     writer.write("TerminalSerialNo,IMEI,Site-Ref,Site-Name\n");
     writer.flush();

     // data
     for(String[] arr: list) {
         String appender = "";
         for(String s : arr){
             writer.write(appender + s);
             appender = ",";
           
         }
         writer.write("\n");
         writer.flush();
     }
     writer.close();`

Comment: Did you try using `\r\n`?

Comment: I have also seen this answer. But this is not really solution. He says copy word then copy on notepad it will work. What do you think this is solution? I know this way work, as I mentioned I used this file in SQL database. Every time I copy this word file then copy again Notepad . this seems unprofessional way.

Comment: thanks \r\n worked. thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I face this problem only notepad.I use "\n" and My Java code like this : ` FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("output.csv");

```
    // headers
    writer.write("TerminalSerialNo,IMEI,Site-Ref,Site-Name\n");
    writer.flush();

    // data
    for(String[] arr: list) {
        String appender = "";
        for(String s : arr){
            writer.write(appender + s);
            appender = ",";

        }
        writer.write("\n");
        writer.flush();
    }
    writer.close();


    `
```

Comment: Adding \r\n and then worked. Thanks for your supporting !

Answer (score 0):

Only in notepad?

Does your Java code use a line break?

```
\n
```

Comment: Yes only in Notepad, I added my Java code. and I also uses new line \n.

Answer (score 0):

use append("\n") and don't forget to close the writer.